# Can't find NewLine with ByteBuffer

Tags: java, sockets, io, byte, nio

Using some SocketChannels with NIO I am passing the key through this method to get a message. However, whenever it passes it displays a newline and I cannot for the life of me find out why and where. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void messageHandler(SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {
        SocketChannel ch = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        buf.clear();
        int read = 0;
        while( (read = ch.read(buf)) > 0 ) {
            buf.flip();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.limit()];
            buf.get(bytes);
            sb.append(new String(bytes));
            buf.clear();
       }
}
```

EDITED: I left a print statement in there by mistake for my own debugging. That has nothing to do with it. I output this to sb.toString() and a new line is contained in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the other end is sending a new line and it is in the `bytes`

Using println() (which auto-flushed by default) can be replaced with print() and flush();

BTW You can use ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes) to avoid copying the bytes twice.

```
for(byte b: bytes)
    if(b == 10 || b == 13) 
         System.err.println("Contains newline");
```

Comment: I checked the other end from everything I can see is not sending a new line.

Comment: I would check what you are receiving. Can you add the code above?

Comment: Is printwriter appropriate for the other side?

Comment: PrintWriter is ok if you don't need to know about IOExceptions writing the data.

Comment: You place the check after `buf.get(bytes);`

Comment: I saw in my printwriter socket output I was using out.println(str), now when I do out.print(str) it doesnt seem to be transmitting

Comment: I got it I had to manually flush afterwards. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It displays a newline because you are calling println().

Comment: Where do you see this? And i left that print statement in there for debugging purposes by mistake..

Comment: You said 'it displays a newline'. Make up your mind. As you didn't post the real code your question isn't actually answerable.

Answer (score 0):

`println()` **print** means print and **ln** means new line, so you can say that it will print then it puts new line 
if you want new line first then use this `print("\n wrint something here");`